# Return items from text file as list in nodeJS

Tags: node.js

Can someone tell me how to return items in a text file as a list. I'm writing code for basic authentication. It registers users then stores their information(first name, last name, gender, password) in a .txt file. I want to be able to confirm a user's password from their file in order to log them in. I'm using the str.split method but it just returns 'undefined'. The 'username' argument in the code below indicates the file name without .txt added to it

```js
const read = (username) => {
    fs.readFile(`${dirPath}/${username}.txt`, 'utf8', (err, item) => {
        console.log(item);
    })
};


const authenticatedUser = (username) => {
    var validUser = doesUserExist("./Database", username);
    if (validUser = true) {
        var user = read(username);
        var userArray = String(user).split(",");
        console.log(userArray);
    }    
};


function doesUserExist (userPath, username) {
    fs.readdir(userPath, (err, files) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("error");
        } else {
            files.forEach(file => {
                 
                if (file == `${username}.txt`) {
                    return true; 
                } else if (file !== `${username}.txt`) {
                    return false; 
                }
            });
        }
             
    });
};
```

Comment: You would also need to provide the code for `doesUserExist()` and `read()` to get an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `read()` as a function that returns a string when it in fact just executes a `fs.readFile()` and then returns nothing.

The quickest way to fix this would be to use `fs.readFileSync()` and make sure to *return that value* from `read()`.

```
const read = (username) => {
    return fs.readFileSync(`${dirPath}/${username}.txt`, {encoding:'utf8'});
};
```

A function that does not return a value intrinsically returns `undefined`.

A more idiomatically correct solution might involve switching to async code:

```
const read = async (username) => {
    return await fs.promises.readFile(`${dirPath}/${username}.txt`, {encoding:'utf8'});
};

const authenticatedUser = async (username) => {
    var validUser = await doesUserExist("./Database", username);
    if (validUser = true) {
        var user = await read(username);
        var userArray = String(user).split(",");
        console.log(userArray);
    }
};

const doesUserExist = async (userPath, username) {
    let returnVal = false;
    const files = await fs.promises.readdir(userPath);
    files.forEach(file => {          
        if (file == `${username}.txt`) {
            returnVal = true;
    });
    return returnVal;
};
```

Using `async` and `await`, you can read your code as if it was synchronous.